# Refresh component after http post

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a modal to add a new project (addProjectModal component)

```
save(data:Project) {
  data.customer_id = this.customerID;
  data.supervisor_id = 450;
  this._projectService.addProject(data)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res)); //maybe init the refresh here
}
```

This component is used in projectComponent where I hold the project data

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.collapsedItem = -1;
  this._projectService.getProjects(this.customerID)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.projects = data
    });
}
```

How would you tell the parent component to refresh (request the new data from database)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say to use

> @Output()

for this...

So html code will look like this:

```
<parentComponent>
     <childComponent tellParent="parentFunction()"></childComponent>
</parentComponent>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it maybe better to use a shared service (singleton)? Is it possible to fill the shared projects array (pout of database) in project service before injecting the service?

Comment: use of shared service is good idea but if you don't have any use in child component so what do want add service reference in child component and all,, but yes could be service is another option

Comment: I use the service in both components...but not yet as singleton

Comment: go with singletone